# Do I have to answer employer when asked about conversations with coworkers?

Tags: communication, human-resources, employer, colleagues, rights

I'm going through a messy situation with my employer ([described here to some extent](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87404/put-on-pip-for-reporting-my-manager-to-hr-what-are-my-options)). I'm still on the PIP despite telling them I will not give the written statement they wanted me to give. They seem to be trying to decide how to get rid of me and in the mean time collect any evidence they can.

One thing I've noticed is that they keep asking me which other employees I've talked to about being on a PIP or other things related to this issue. Am I required to answer this question? Can someone suggest a professional way to refrain from answering this question?

I feel like this line of questioning will only cause trouble for the other people I've spoken to, but I do not want to lie either. For the record, I haven't been telling people about everything going on. A few of the employees closer to me know some of it, and it has become obvious to others that there is something going on between me and the management because of the extensive meetings with HR and my manager's attitude. I'd appreciate if anyone could give an example of a good blanket statement to use to respond to this. That is if you think refraining from answering is a good idea. Up to this point I've been answering these questions with the names of the people and what I've told them.

Comment: Get a lawyer. Yesterday!

Comment: Best to get legal advice, they are best suited to inform you of your rights and how to respond to these requests.

Comment: And the blanket statements we use in these scenarios are: [I plead the fifth](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plead%20the%20fifth), [no comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_comment) and just [silence](http://tinybuddha.com/blog/why-silence-is-often-the-best-response-to-a-verbal-attack/). But I agree and have upvoted all the other comments about this becoming a legal issue.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's fair for your employer(HR and some level of management) to ask you about what you are doing at work. You are in their building and getting paid for your time.  If you aren't willing to talk about it, don't do it on their dime.

Comment: what PIP stand for?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I assume it's Personal Improvement Plan in this context.  That's an HR euphemism for when they are trying to sack someone for lack of competence.  Basically, the OP is undergoing disciplinary measures.

Answer (score 12):

You write:

> I feel like this line of questioning will only cause trouble for the
>   other people I've spoken to, but I do not want to lie either.

I fully agree with that. Both in general, and specifically in your situation, I can see no good coming from telling your boss about what you said to coworkers. So just say:

> I am sorry, that was a private conversation.

Or, if your boss asks whether you talked about it at all:

> I am sorry, I cannot give you information on my private conversations.

If they insist, just repeat that.

They may not like that answer, but apparently they don't like you anyway, so it does not seem it matters what you do.

Of course, they may ask the other person, and that person may answer - be prepared for that. Beyond that, there's not much you can do.

Legally, I don't think you are required to report your conversations with coworkers. There may be certain things you are not allowed to tell them (or not), but in that case the burden of proof is on your employer. If you are unsure on that point, consider contacting a lawyer or some other legal help (such as a local trade union or similar). You could also ask on https://law.stackexchange.com/ .

To avoid the problem in the future, you could try to avoid talking to others when your boss can notice, but that may not always be practical.

---

On a general note, I find it highly unprofessional and impolite to insist on details about someone else's conversation. If there is a well-founded suspicion that there was something illegitimate going on (harassment, transmission of company secrets, ...) an employer can ask about that specifically, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually haven't talked to anyone when my boss is around. However, my boss is not trying to keep it secret that they are trying to build a case against me and he keeps on asking who I've shared certain information with. I guess the "private conversation" line will have to do for now.

Comment: "I am afraid I am not responsible for what other people think; it seems it is obvious that something is going on with me and they will probably have their own thoughts, but I can not know what they are." - not quite answering your bosses' question, but might deflect the issue to make clear that they are more responsible for people talking than you.

Comment: Saying "That was a private conversation" confirms that a conversation took place.  That's already giving them too much information.

Comment: Also not sure what expectation of privacy you have in the workplace.  While your boss may not have a right to know, HR and some level of management may.  If you want privacy have those conversations on your time off premise.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom: Good point. I was thinking of a situation where the employer already knows there was a conversation. I edited to improve.

Comment: @cdkMoose: "expectation of privacy" generally refers to the case where the employer alredy has (found out / overheard / logged) information you want to keep private. This is about being required to supply the information yourself, which I believe is different. Of course, it's still best to talk in private.

Comment: @sleske I'm sure the employer does already know; but there's no good that can come from going on record as confirming what they think they know.

Comment: @sleske, I say expectation of privacy because of the suggestion to claim it was a private conversation.  It's possible that employer could claim it's not private if it's on premise on company time.    You can't necessarily just say it's private and that makes it so.  If company wants to be a real pain, they could say, "fine, if it was private, you clearly weren't working, so we are docking your pay" or some other penalty

Comment: @cdkMoose: True, the company could claim any of that, but it does not really matter, because "private" here is just a polite word for "something I do not want to tell you" - that's what the question is about. Obviously the boss can raise objections to that, but that's a different question - and that could happen with any phrase OP uses.